# Error in Deploying Java Enterprise Application on Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I have an enterprise application and on deploying I get the following error message.

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error
>   creating managed object for class
>   org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener. Please see
>   server.log for more details.

How do I go about solving it?

Comment: Show your `server.log`, and read exceptions with care.

Comment: Clean & Build your project, restart Glassfish and redeploy. If this doesn't help, update the question with the complete exception stacktrace.